# How to use the First and Rest functions?

Tags: racket

I am trying to use First and Rest to iterate over a list of numbers in racket but I am not sure I am using these functions correctly because the code is not working.

```
(define cubed
  (lambda (a)
    (* a a a)))

(define (all-elements-cubed a)
  (cond
    [(empty? a) empty]
    [else 
     (+ 1 (all-elements-cubed (cubed (first (rest a)))))]))

(all-elements-cubed (list 1 2 3 7 5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `first` and `rest` procedures are the most basic building blocks for traversing a list recursively. The names are self-describing: they access the first element of a list, and the rest of the elements in a list (after the first). In your code, they should be used together with `cons` - the procedure for *constructing* lists, like this:

```
(define (all-elements-cubed a)
  (cond
    [(empty? a) empty]
    [else 
     (cons ; we're building a new list as output, so `cons` a new element
      (cubed (first a)) ; call `cubed` on the first element
      (all-elements-cubed (rest a)))])) ; and proceed to the next elements
```

To understand why the above works remember the way we use `cons` for recursively building proper lists:

```
(cons <element> <list>)
```

For example:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 empty))
=> '(1 2)
```